# how to get the license key for windows10 developer edition on virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vmware, operating-systems, license

Hi I've downloaded windows10 image for VirtualBox (from microsoft website) and is working fine. But I see bottom right corner of my guest OS, license expires in xx days. I tried entering my windows10 home edition key under settings>update&security>activation>change product key. But it doesn't take, as mine being home edition.

Also at Microsoft website, where I download the image, I see a message "This VM will expire on 1/10/21." So, what's after? I am using it for personal learning purpose only. Is there a way to get permanent copy?

Or is there a better location that I can download the image, never expires? Student version/personal learning. Any suggestions really appreciated.

I don't mind purchasing if its not too expensive.

[image]

Comment: You can always download a new VM after this one expires.

Answer (score 1):

> Also at Microsoft website, where I download the image, I see a message "This VM will expire on 1/10/21." So, what's after?

It’s not looking for anything since it’s not possible to license the VM in question.  Furthermore, you cannot activate a Windows 10 Enterprise installation with a Windows 10 Home license.  Windows 10 Enterprise can only be purchased as a volume license key.

> Is there a way to get permanent copy?

You would have to create your own VM and install Windows 10 Home.  This will only work if your license currently isn’t in use.

> Or is there a better location that I can download the image, never expires?

There is no such thing as a free Windows installation.  Windows licenses never expired.  Any license provided to students are paid by their educational institution.

> Student version/personal learning.

Your current VM is what Microsoft offers as a non-permanent solution.  If you want a permanent solution you will have to purchase Windows 10.

Comment: @YempiP - Windows 10 OEM devices do not have their license printed on a sticker.  Microsoft discontinued that practice over a decade ago.